# how to implement a basic custom dataProcessor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

are there any examples online on how to implement a basic dataProcessor in CKEditor to use your own syntax?

From what I understand ( http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Data_Processor ) you basically only need 2 functions: toHtml and toDataFormat.

You would also need to implement the said interface.

And then?

Could my functions only contain some RegExp and then use the new dataProcessor as Plugin?

The BBCode-Plugin seems to do muuch more then that.

Any examples (let's say you want to replace `<b>Text</b>` with `**Text**`) would be great!

I'm really struggling to find something on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play this way:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        getData: function( event ) {
            event.data.dataValue = event.data.dataValue.replace( /<\/?b[^>]*>/g, '**' );
        }
    }
});
```

This is, however, a very naive and poor implementation. To have something more, please consider current [bbcode plugin implementation](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/bbcode/plugin.js). Then you'll find that the problem is much more complex than it seemes to be.

Good luck anyway! ;)

Comment: Learning from BBCode plugin is not a good idea. It isn't working very well and it's a little bit hacky. We need to rewrite it and possibly also change few things in dataProcessor interface, because it doesn't satisfy all needs for implementing different output format like BBCode or Markdown.

But still... I can't give you a better example than BBCode plugin, so Olek's right - good luck :).

PS. data processing will probably change quite soon. It has high priority for us.

Comment: @Reinmar thanks for that hint (: So if I plan to do something sustainable I would better be of to wait 1 or 2 releases?

Comment: I cannot promise anything, but I would say that in few months (~4-5) we will improve data processing. Note that it won't be in 4.0.x bug-fixing releases, but because of size of this task after few of them. It's hard to say how quickly we'll reach acceptable stability of v4.